# ORA-01440 error from setting precision of 38 on a NULL precision column with data?

Tags: database, oracle

In an Oracle database I work with, many NUMBER columns were originally created with NULL precision. My understanding is that these columns have implicit maximum precision. (Per Oracle: "If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given.") They currently contain data.

The maximum precision I can explicitly specify for a new column is 38. However, when I attempt to modify these existing columns to set this explicit precision, Oracle throws an error:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table
MODIFY column NUMBER(38);
```

> ORA-01440: column to be modified must be empty to decrease precision or scale

If 38 is the maximum, how am I decreasing precision by setting that number?

The alternative approaches to changing this type (e.g., creating a new column, copying data, dropping/re-adding constraints, etc.) are quite laborious relative to the modify statement.

Comment: `NUMBER(38, 6)`?

Comment: Does the current column have a scale for this `NUMBER` type? By not specifying one you are setting scale to 0 which may be a decrease.

Comment: Indeed, though the column did not have a scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in quoting Oracle that

> If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given

and

> The maximum precision I can explicitly specify for a new column is 38

But that **doesn't mean** that the **maximal precision** that **Oracle can store is 38**.

Here a simple example - assume that your column is defined without `precision`and with `scale` zero:

```
create table MyTable 
(num1 NUMBER(*,0)
);
```

You may verify this in the table disctionary

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE 
from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'MYTABLE';

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
------------------------------ -------------- ----------
NUM1                                                   0
```

Now let's fill some data

```
insert into MyTable(num1) values(sqrt(2)*power(10,38) );
```

Actually you got a `precision` of 39 (I'm on Windows  this behaviour may be OS dependent, but Oracle must count with the possibility)

```
select num1 from MyTable;

141421356237309504880168872420969807857

select length(to_char(num1)) from MyTable;
39
```

So you see you can't simple overwrite the `precision` with the *maximal allowed precision* of 38 - this could mean a real decrease.

Similar situation is if the column is defined **without scale and precision**

```
create table MyTable 
(num1 NUMBER 
); 

select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE 
from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'MYTABLE';

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
------------------------------ -------------- ----------
NUM1
```

Contrary to popular belief and the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832) in this case **doesn't hold**:

> If no scale is specified, the scale is zero.

On the contrary the `scale` may be higher that 38 as you see in the example below:

```
insert into MyTable(num1) values(sqrt(2)/10);

select num1 from MyTable;

0,141421356237309504880168872420969807857
```

There are 39 decimal digits in the figure.

**Summary**

You can't set the `precision` without a reorganizing the table.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you. "You can't set the precision without a reorganizing the table." --> Which is what I was trying to avoid, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> The maximum precision I can explicitly specify for a new column is 38
>   ...
>
> If 38 is the maximum, how am I decreasing precision by setting that number?

That is the maximum you can declare, as the *p* constraint in NUMBER(*p*, *s*). It is often thought that means that Oracle doesn't allow numbers of more than 38 digits even if unconstrained, but that isn't quite true. Even if you only constrain the scale you can have more; e.g. with a column of data type INTEGER, which has no precision constraint but does have a scale of 0.

The [documentation for the NUMBER data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78) (12cR2) includes:

> Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to 20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits

With a column with unconstrained precision you can have more than 38 significant digits. Some sample tables to demonstrate against:

```
create table t1 (num number);
create table t2 (num integer);
create table t3 (num number(38));
create table t4 (num number(38,0));

select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale
from user_tab_columns
where table_name in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4');

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
---------- ------------ --------- ----------- -------------- ----------
T1         NUM          NUMBER             22                          
T2         NUM          NUMBER             22                         0
T3         NUM          NUMBER             22             38          0
T4         NUM          NUMBER             22             38          0
```

then this is allowed:

```
insert into t1 values (power(10, 39)+1);
```

as is, in fact, this:

```
insert into t1 values (power(10, 40)+1);

1 row inserted.
```

When you look at the data, as reported in a SQL Developer worksheet with `numwidth` set to 42, you see:

```
select num, length(to_char(num)) from t1;

                                       NUM                       LENGTH(TO_CHAR(NUM))
------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
  1000000000000000000000000000000000000001                                         40
 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                         40
```

The first row has 40 significant digits and the exact value is preserved. (The second row has lost the +1 from the insert, as it's now too large for internal precision in the quote above. The length is still reported as 40 without an explicit format mask, which is mildly interesting. Otherwise that row isn't helpful...)

An INTEGER column, which is NUMBER(,0), allows the same:

```
insert into t2 values (power(10, 39)+1);

1 row inserted.

select num, length(to_char(num)) from t2;

                                       NUM                       LENGTH(TO_CHAR(NUM))
------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
  1000000000000000000000000000000000000001                                         40
```

But once you constrain the precision that is no longer allowed:

```
insert into t3 values (power(10, 39)+1);

ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

insert into t3 values (power(10, 38)+1);

ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

insert into t3 values (power(10, 37)+1);

1 row inserted.

select num, length(to_char(num)) from t3;

                                       NUM                       LENGTH(TO_CHAR(NUM))
------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
    10000000000000000000000000000000000001                                         38
```

If you constraint the scale as well, to zero anyway, it behaves the same; inserting and querying `t4` gets the same results.

So the point is that a plain `NUMBER` column is *not* the same as a `NUMBER(38, 0)` column, and your `alter` statement *is* actually reducing the theoretical maximum precision of the column. Oracle doesn't check the actual values in a column before throwing ORA-01440, so it doesn't matter than none of the existing values actually exceed the precision you are trying to specify - it just knows that they *could*.

Comment: This is an answer just as excellent as the one above, I wish I could pick both. Thank you!